# Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-4, windows, compatibility

The RPi 4 B with 4 GB of RAM has been released quite a while ago and out of curiosity I was thinking about if it could run Windows 10. There is a video about the pertaining topic but Windows 10 seems to be very sluggish even on the recent Raspberry Pi 3 B+. Ever since that day nobody has ever tried to run windows on the new model (Rpi 4 B). Does anybody know if this could work on this? I'm pretty sure it could **"probably"** run on it since of:

- Increased RAM
- Increased processor power
- Better graphics (now supporting 4K)
- Etc.

I know this seems like a very stupid question. I mean, why would anybody want to do this? We already have Debian running on it why Windows now? The reason to this is: more support. More support for applications, and so. Since this model is running a 64-bit processor, that means, if you would install windows, then you would be able to enable [**WSL**](https://www.google.com/search?q=wsl+windows) (view doc [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) if you don't know about it) onto the raspberry pi and **also** run Debian **on top** of Windows. Making this a reality (to me) seems like a great option and  I fully support it. Does anybody know if this'll work?

Comment: Ah, let me see. I agree that as you said, Win10 could "probably" run on Rpi4B. The problem is that the relatively very very weak Rpi hardware with very very strong Win10 would "probably" run ridiculously slow, otherwise all the evil WinTel PC manufacturers would have to go broke now.

Comment: I have also wanted to do this. I tried to install Win10 with WOA-Deployer-Rpi project but [this issue](https://github.com/WOA-Project/WOA-Deployer-Rpi/issues/47) holds me off.

Comment: @Biswapriyo It's really cool. I even didn't know something has developed like that. As you sent a post there, you faced a problem at the first step, am I right?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'm gonna test.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a [test](http://enter%20code%20here) of the pi 4 speed compared to a 3b+, and using an SSD, SD and a flash drive as store. And to be fair, the pi 4 with SSD seemed to be a bit sluggish as a desktop Debian, so why would you want to try it with windows 10?

But the answer to your question, HW wise it could run it, SW we need drivers and what not to work.